# Shortcut Ctrl + Alt + R doesn't work in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using *PyCharm* on a *Windows* machine, and I'm running the tutorial found [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/django_guide.html).

It keeps on telling me to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> as some sort of command. I don't know what I did, but this does sweet diddly for me on *Windows*. I think because I'm using *Eclipse* shortcuts?

Anyway, anyone have any idea what the menu item is for this thing? So using the GUI I can find it? Or even what it is called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> is a hotkey for **Tools | Run manage.py task** menu item.

It seems to be unmapped in Eclipse keymap. Open **IDE Settings | Keymap** section, search there for 'manage.py' and map the action to a hotkey.

Answer (score 4):

This issue also comes when you rename `settings.py` file or the `project directory` name with something else. In this case you need to follow these steps.

1. In the Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S) under the Languages and Frameworks node, click Django.
2. Check the setting box. It should be blank if you have renamed or moved `settings.py` file into other folder. Here you have to select the new `settings.py` file. click ok and
   now Ctrl+Alt+R should work.

Comment: I wish PyCharm would throw a message here! Like, Languages & Frameworks > Django > Settings is currently empty. I had just separated out my settings files to base, dev, and prod.